# VBA VLookup that selects Multiple Values Into once Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a VBA project for work. I am trying to write a VBA code that will return multiple values into one cell when selecting values from a Data Validation Drop Down list. I have not made much progress however. I will post the code I am working on and two other codes that do similar functions independently.

This is the code I have been working on. Zone is the reference to the sheet that has the values I am trying to use:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
Dim lOld As Long
Dim selectedNa As String
Dim selectedNum As String
Dim selectedNum1 As String
Dim selectedNa1 As String

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  selectedNa = Target.Value
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Zones").Range("Zone"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
            oldVal = Target.Value
    Else
        lOld = Len(oldVal)
          If Left(newVal, lOld) <> selectedNa Then
            selectedNa1 = Target.Value
              selectedNum1 = Application.VLookup(selectedNa1, Worksheets("Zones").Range("Zone"), 2, False)
                If Not IsError(selectedNum1) Then
                  Target.Value = selectedNum1
                  newVal = Target.Value
        If oldVal = "" Then
          'do nothing
          Else
          If newVal = "" Then
          'do nothing
            Else
              If Left(newVal, lOld) = oldVal Then
                Target.Value = newVal
                    Else
                      lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
                      If lUsed > 0 Then
                        Target.Value = oldVal
                        Else
                            Target.Value = oldVal _
                            & "|" & newVal
              End If
            End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
    End If
  End If
  End If
End If


exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is a code that allows you to select multiple values from a drop down list without a vlookup:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
Dim lOld As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lOld = Len(oldVal)
        If Left(newVal, lOld) = oldVal Then
          Target.Value = newVal
        Else
          lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
          If lUsed > 0 Then
              Target.Value = oldVal
          Else
              Target.Value = oldVal _
                & "|" & newVal
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And lastly this is a code that performs a vlookup. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    selectedNa = Target.Value
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Zones").Range("Zone"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
            oldVal = Target.Value
```

Comment: Hi, can u provides some exemples of datas

Comment: So in one sheet I have two columns. "Zones" and "stores". In the next sheet I have a column "delivered to". The goal is to use a vlookup in the delivered column that allows me to select a zone and the stores will pop up. In addition I want to be able to select multiple zones to in that same cell and separate them with a "|".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to easely populate a combobox

```
Sub FormsStyleComboBox()
    ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(411, 14.25, 124.5, 188.25).Select
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    strng = Range("A1:A" & N).Address
    Selection.ListFillRange = strng
End Sub
```

That is how you fill a combo from a list

[image]

Comment: I understand how to do that. I am trying to use a Vlookup and have the cell use multiple if I select multiple from the drop down list.